# how to do voice/video chat in android using smack api's

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

We are already using jabber smack api for chating in our application.

now we are planing to upgrade my app by adding voice/video chat.

I think its possible by using the jingle jabber smack but i am not getting any api's or sample code in jave for jingle.

can any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 8):

Well, the [Beem Project](http://www.beem-project.com/) is working [on this too](http://www.beem-project.com/hg/jingle/summary). Maybe you find here some hints about jingle implementation in Java and Android.

But providing voice and video calls via XMPP is not so trival. smacks jingle branch is pretty old and I am not sure if the API reflects the current state of the [jingle specification](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0166.html). But it was implemented as a [Google SoC project.](http://wiki.xmpp.org/web/Java_Jingle) This may a hint of a solid API. You have to try yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Quickblox for android thay are handling video chat

http://quickblox.com/