# Android video chat using XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, videochat, libjingle

I've been investigating the best way to develop a video chat application on android that:

**a)** Is straight P2P

**OR**

**b)** Can take advantage of existing services (gtalk?) that already support video chat to handle communications while being able to maintain a custom interfaced app

For this I was considering using XMPP + Jingle. I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769020/android-and-xmpp-currently-available-solutions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189401/how-to-do-voice-video-chat-in-android-using-smack-apis), and I'm not sure if this idea is viable atm. What I would like to know is if it is in fact possible to use jingle on android and what, in your opinion, would be the best library/API from those available (patched smack, official smack, asmack, beem's asmack..) to use given my purpose.

I would also appreciate opinions regarding if option A or B are best (or even possible, since I'm not sure option B is).

Comment: I have a similar mission to be implemented as yours. Whats your recommendation Rick?

Comment: @AKh I'm afraid that at the time I concluded that what I wanted to do couldn't be done without a lot of effort so I gave up..the easy alternative was using SIP (you have linphone for android)..

Answer (score 1):

I have researched Beem for about 1 week and I found Beem does not completely implement the Application types and transport method of jingle.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm posting this answer to help people searching about android video chat I think the best way is to user android webrtc
 use this as client

[android client](https://github.com/firaschmek/AppRTCDemo)

and use this as server

[server](https://github.com/firaschmek/apprtc-node-server)
 I'm posting this after weeks and weeks of search so believe me this is the best solution

Comment: While this links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes