# broadcasting live video from android to server

Tags: android, xmpp, chat

hello i am developing an application which perform live chat on android , so i am using 
    XMPP protocol (Jabber) , so i am able to perform text chat on it now i want to do 
    video chat on that . so can anybody give me some idea about it. how to perform 
    broadcasting of video from android to server and also format of passing data to the 
    server ?

i am passing text data in this format

```
        String to = mRecipient.getText().toString();
            String text = mSendText.getText().toString();

            Log.i("XMPPClient", "Sending text [" + text + "] to [" + to
                    + "]");
            Message msg = new Message(to, Message.Type.chat);
            msg.setBody(text);
            connection.sendPacket(msg);
            messages.add(connection.getUser() + ":");
            messages.add(text);
```

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189401/how-to-do-voice-video-chat-in-android-using-smack-apis