# How to implement Audio/Video Chat using asmack in android with openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, voip, openfire, videochat

I am working on Xmpp based chat app, I am using Asmack library in Android, and Openfire as server.
I have implemented one to one chat and group chat successfully, now i want to add Audio/Video chat in  that, I am searching it on Google but not got enough help.

we can implement this functionality using Asterisk/JITS video bridge plugin to openfire right? and also is there any other plugins?

And also I have not found any help regarding how to implement this functionality in android. So, if any one can help me regarding this? any link or other stuff that will help me please let me know.

Any help is appreciated !

Thank you !

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to do voice/video chat in android using smack api's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7189401/how-to-do-voice-video-chat-in-android-using-smack-apis)

Comment: @legoscia i have checked this post, but not found any help, and i dont want to use quckblox or bheem project.

Comment: i want to implement this functionality with openfire.

Comment: Any success? Have you considered webrtc??

Comment: @Y.S Did you get any working code for this? Please advice..